# Issue with python serial: ValueError: Attempting to use a port that is not open

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, pyserial, uart

I am trying to get the data from a blood pressure monitor using the python in raspberry pi3. I googled and found a few examples to get the data using python.

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import serial
neo = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/ttyUSB0',
    baudrate=9600,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout=0
)
print("connected to: " + neo.portstr)

#neo.open()      #opens port
print "Is port open ? ",neo.isOpen()    #returns true?

#ser.write("help\n");
while True:
    dataline = neo.readline();
    if dataline:
        print(dataline), neo.close()
```

When I ran above code using "**sudo python pyusb.py**" command, it is returning the following error:

```
connected to: /dev/ttyUSB0
Is port open ?  True
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyusb.py", line 18, in <module>
    dataline = neo.readline();
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 443, in read
    if not self._isOpen: raise portNotOpenError
ValueError: Attempting to use a port that is not open
```

If un-commented the line "**neo.open()**" it is throwing another error:

```
connected to: /dev/ttyUSB0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyusb.py", line 13, in <module>
    neo.open()      #opens port
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 271, in open
    raise SerialException("Port is already open.")
serial.serialutil.SerialException: Port is already open.
```

I have looked at the similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30246659/issues-with-pyserial-port-must-be-configured-before-it-can-be-used). But there is a issue with overriding of "**serial.Serial()**" method. I am unable to identify exactly what is the wrong with code above. Can anyone help me with, what I am doing wrong there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look at the docs for pyserial, http://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shortintro.html#readline it says you must specify a timeout when using `readline()`.  This is because `readline()` waits for a EOL character at the end of each transmission.  Try increasing the timeout to 1 using something like this:

```
import serial
neo = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/ttyUSB0',
    baudrate=9600,
    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
    timeout=1
)
print("connected to: " + neo.portstr)

while True:
    dataline = neo.readline();
    print dataline
```

Comment: Thanks Nick Hale. timeout = 1 worked. But I am still getting the port is not open issue even I received the data. If I commented the line "neo.close()", that error disappears. what is the wrong with that? Am I trying to close the port improperly?

Comment: so `neo.close` will close the port altogether, to re-open it, you would need to use `neo.open`  Why do you need to close it like that? It will close when the python script is exited.  You don't need to close it between reads, it doesn't work like `file.open()` and `file.close()`

Comment: Just to clarify, you would open it (using `neo = serial.Serial(...)`) and then read as many times as you like - when you like, once the port is open it stays open and can be read from or written to anytime.

Comment: Oh ok. I thought it will block the port until I close it. Thanks for the help.